# Unique lists within list of lists if those lists have list as one of the elements

Tags: python, list, function, set, tuples

If I have:

```
l = [['98765', ['Einstein, A', 'SFEN'], 'SSW 540', 3], ['98765', ['Einstein, A', 'SFEN'], 'SSW 540', 3],
     ['98764', ['Feynman, R', 'SFEN'], 'SSW 564', 3], ['98764', ['Feynman, R', 'SFEN'], 'SSW 564', 3]]
```

What would be the best way to get:

```
k = [['98765', 'Einstein, A', 'SFEN', 'SSW 540', 3], ['98764', 'Feynman, R', 'SFEN', 'SSW 564', 3]]
```

If I try:

```
uniqinstruct = set(map(tuple, l))
```

I get `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`. I don't want to remove all layers of nesting, because that would just combine everything into one list:

```
output = []

def reemovNestings(l):
    for i in l:
        if type(i) == list:
            reemovNestings(i)
        else:
            output.append(i)

reemovNestings(l)
print(sorted(set(output), key=output.index))
```

Output:

```
['98765', 'Einstein, A', 'SFEN', 'SSW 540', 3, '98764', 'Feynman, R', 'SSW 564']
```

If two instructors have the same count (i.e. 3 in this case), then only one 3 remains because it's a `set`, and I can't group the elements of the list by every `x` intervals. What would be a good way to preserve that last value?

Comment: Could we merge those list with the same number like `"98765"` or `"98764"`?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists help?

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA That number is a unique identifier, but could be repeated if an instructor teaches multiple courses (with different course names and counts), so would not be good to merge

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Looks like `flatten` from `django` and then collecting by every 5 elements could work as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you know which layer you want to unwrap, you could just iterate through that layer. In your particular example, it's the second layer:

```
res = []
for inner_list in l:
    inner = []
    for el in inner_list:
        if type(el) == list:
            inner.extend(el)
        else:
            inner.append(el)
    if not (inner in res):
        res.append(inner)
```

Note that `list.extend` adds multiple values to the list.

`if not (inner in res): res.append(inner)` gives you unique items in the top layer. Thanks to @dmitryro for the tip.

Comment: you probably want to check   `if not (inner in res): res.append(inner)` as he's only interested in non-repeating items.

Comment: Yep, you are right. I got blind there and realized the need for non-repeating elements after I finished the code snipped. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

use `itertools.groupby` to divided them, and flatten them by a list comprehension. To ensure the order of list, you could use `dict.fromkeys()`.

If you don't mind this too long list comprehension:

```
from itertools import groupby

l = [['98765', ['Einstein, A', 'SFEN'], 'SSW 540', 3], ['98765', ['Einstein, A', 'SFEN'], 'SSW 540', 3],
     ['98764', ['Feynman, R', 'SFEN'], 'SSW 564', 3], ['98764', ['Feynman, R', 'SFEN'], 'SSW 564', 3]]

s = [list(dict.fromkeys(e for i in item for j in i for e in (j if type(j) is list else [j])).keys()) for _, item in groupby(l)]
print(s)
```

Result:

```
[['98765', 'Einstein, A', 'SFEN', 'SSW 540', 3], ['98764', 'Feynman, R', 'SFEN', 'SSW 564', 3]]
```

Comment: Python 3.6 + dictionary will keep the order of insert.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Numpy.unique](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) with flatten list.

`np.unique(flattened, axis=0)`

Comment: Change `print(sorted(set(output), key=output.index))` to `print(np.unique(output, axis=0))`

Answer (score 0):

Here's another possible solution.

First, flatten the original list:

```
def flatten(s):
    if s == []:
        return s
    if isinstance(s[0], list):
        return flatten(s[0]) + flatten(s[1:])
    return s[:1] + flatten(s[1:])
```

Your original input:

```
l = [['98765', ['Einstein, A', 'SFEN'], 'SSW 540', 3], 
     ['98765', ['Einstein, A', 'SFEN'], 'SSW 540', 3],
     ['98764', ['Feynman, R', 'SFEN'], 'SSW 564', 3], 
     ['98764', ['Feynman, R', 'SFEN'], 'SSW 564', 3]]
```

Now let's flatten and iterate over it

```
final = [] # the resulting list

items = flatten(l) # first flatten the input

# take every 5 elements and add them to the final list, if not there yet.
for i in range(0, len(items), 5):
    if not (items[i:i+5] in final):
        final.append(items[i:i+5])

#let's print [['98765', 'Einstein, A', 'SFEN', 'SSW 540', 3], 
              ['98764', 'Feynman, R', 'SFEN', 'SSW 564', 3]]
print(final)
```